# How to implement a scroll view with a header layout in HTML

Tags: css, html, layout

I'm wondering how to implement the below layout by using HTML.

I don't know how to let the blue `div` fill the rest of the height.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO can help you with your markup but SO does not write mark up for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) and `overflow: auto` (change `50px` on `header` to your desired height).

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ED7D31;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background: #5B9BD5;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner">Content HEre</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Other solution using `calc()`

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ED7D31;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background: #5B9BD5;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner">Content HEre</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about the traditional layout solution. I don't know how to implement this   layout without using flex

Comment: What is `traditional layout solution` `:)` ?

Comment: What I mean traditional layout is that layout based on box model

Comment: @CharlesWei - all visual layouts, including flexbox, are based on the box model.

Comment: Sorry, for the unclear reply. 
What I really mean traditional layout is the layout model widely supported among the most of browsers.
I knew flex layout is a new thing. Maybe It's not stable among browsers.

Comment: If you don't need support for IE9 or less you can use flexbox http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox, else you can use calc http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but it looks quite easy:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <header></header>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
header{
  height:200px;
  background-color:orange;
}
div{
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5umwj5j2/4/

So Basically the idea is that height 100% for blue div means "make blue div as high as his parent" - but this is why you need to set height for the parent - in my case the parent is body and body parent is html.

Comment: That extends the blue div *past* the bottom of the window.

Comment: I argee with @Quentin